# tkinter not working when run from command line python script

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am an experience programmer, but relatively new to Python.

I have developed a fairly complex Python program on Raspberry Pi - in thonny, Raspbian/buster v10 - Python 3.7.3.

It uses tkinter, and works fine in thonny, but fails to create anything when the .py script is run from the command line.

I have reduced the program to a bare minimum, and it behaves the same:

:Run from thonny it works - I get the tkinter window

:Invoke python3 from CLI and enter commands individually - also works

But if I have it running in a script (test.py), the script runs fine (I get output) but no window appears.

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()  #produces small window in thonny & python3-line-by-line
                     #but nothing when the test.py script is run
print ('test")       #to prove program is actually running
while 1:   #loop to stop program terminating
   l=3
```

No error messages.

Comment: Add `root.mainloop()` instead that while loop.

Comment: My word, that was quick!!! Thanks - that has sorted it for the test program.

But it doesn't fix it in the real program (which has 12 modules and about 4800 lines of code) - it's basically a non-interactive slide-show, and I use a canvas. A timing loop creates the image on a canvas, occasionally downloading new images.I appreciate that doesn't provide sufficient information to help, but just provides the context.

Now I know where to look, I'll try again - and use update/update_idletasks instead to avoid blocking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `root.mainloop()` at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter applications need to be able to process a steady flow of events. Tkinter is single threaded (meaning: it can only do one thing at a time). By creating that infinite loop you've made it impossible for tkinter to service any events and thus the window will appear frozen (or not appear at all, since the drawing of the window is itself a response to an event).

You should remove your `while` loop and replace it with a call to `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: Many thanks - also for the quick reply.

The while loop replaces a whole bunch of processing, including downloading JSON files, downloading images, displaying images on the canvas, multiple-error checks on network status and more. If I replace that loop, root.mainloop() will block and nothing happen  - so presumably I need to use update - I will experiment where it would go.

Answer (score 0):

The answer wasn't root.mainloop() exactly, because that would block any other code - but it pointed me in the right direction and I looked at root.update and root.update_idletasks .

I've pulled all the slide/canvas updates into a single function and added update/update_idletasks and it works in both thonny and via the command line.

Thanks for a very quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

Try using pycharm. I just fixed that problem. I realized that jupyter won't work

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I was trying to execute following command: `$ python PATH_TO_PYTHON_SCRIPT`. This always failed. The correct way to launch the script was `$python3 PATH_TO_PYTHON_SCRIPT`.